# How to interpret error while camera calibrating

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration

I'm trying to calibrate camera using MatLab.
Is reprojection error a distance between a pattern keypoint detected in a calibration image, and a corresponding world point projected into the same image?
It shows Overall Mean Error (for example 0.86 pixels) and that's what I want to understand.
Does 0 is the best result?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/evaluating-the-accuracy-of-single-camera-calibration.html), and try to revise your question to something more "answerable".  Someone can't tell if 0.86 pixels is good enough. The best result is probably zero.

Comment: I published my question after reading documentation. Si 0.86 means that real pixels are shifted by 0.86 pixel? Am I right?

Comment: I don't know the exact meaning (I am trying to direct you for asking a valid question)... You may ask what does it mean: "A reprojection error is the distance between a pattern keypoint detected in a calibration image, and a corresponding world point projected into the same image"? It's a bit out of topic, because it's not a programming question, but questions like that are often answered. Don't forget to add reference to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Exactly. That's one of my questions.

Comment: Your question is better, but still requires revising. Zero error is the minimum (you don't need to ask that). The formal definition of "reprojection error" is documented (you don't need to ask if it's true or false). You can ask for someone to clarify the formal definition of "reprojection error" so you can understand it. Try to ask just that (remove the "Overall Mean Error" part). If you don't get an answer, don't be disappointed - it's a difficult question.